# Class file parser

Tags: java, parsing, .class-file

I have an assignment where i need to write a Java program that parses a .class file and retrieves things like :

1.name of the .java file

2.implemented interfaces

3.variables

4.constructors

5.methods

I don't have any ideeas where to begin from?
For example,what kind of Data I/O structure should I use?

Comment: can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I looked upon the term you just mentioned and i think i kind of understand

Comment: Hey, sorry for removing my comment so quickly. I hesitated as you mentioned a .class file and I thought you'd have to parse bytecodes. Java "reflection" is an API that allows you to get information of a class or even set accessibility of protected fields and methods of the class.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`ClassParser`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/apidocs/org/apache/bcel/classfile/ClassParser.html) which is available in [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi).

Alternatively, load the class using Java normally, and then use the Java Reflection API which provides methods such as [`getDeclaredFields`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--), [`getDeclaredMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--), etc.

Comment: It made the trick, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

There are already several libraries for classfile parsing out there. Objectweb ASM is the most popular.

If you have to do it from scratch, that I'd recommend starting by the [JVM specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html), which explains the binary layout of classfiles in detail. After that, parsing is just a simple matter of programming. I've written a classfile parser before, it's not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any external library, just use `java.lang.Class`. Write the name of your class:

```
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredFields();
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredConstructors();
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

It's the same for interfaces and many other attributes.

Comment: -1. Reflection requires the class to be loaded, which may be undesirable or impossible (say, if it conflicts with classes in the program that is doing the introspection, or if its dependencies are not available).  Reflection is not a substitute for reading a class file without loading it.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK actually comes with an API that lets you parse and manipulate class files programmatically that most programmers don't know about. It is located at the package `com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Java Reflection. Here is a good tutorial -->

[Java Reflection Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/)

Comment: -1. Reflection requires you to actually load and execute the class. Not exactly a classfile parser.