# Is there a way to inspect class, field and method level annotations in an "unloaded" java class file?

Tags: java

I would like to inspect annotations present in a java class file without requiring any of it's dependedencies to be loaded, only requiring the loading of the basic JVM libraries and the class file in question only.

To load a class at runtime in java requires a classpath having it's field, method, and parameter dependencies findable.  I want to do this in an environment where non of those other files may exist.

Is this possible? is there an available library to do this?

Comment: Almost any bytecode manipulation library will provide that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261947/are-there-alternatives-to-cglib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple: then you do not want to **load** the class.

You consider the class as a **class file** living in the file system.

In other words: it is a resource containing binary data - which you then parse. Either yourself, or by using a library that does that for you (which would be the sane, preferred way instead of re-inventing the wheel).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24697562/class-file-parser) for a list of options how to do that. Or you directly turn to the [asm](http://asm.ow2.org/) byte code parser.

Comment: Yes a parser library twould be best, Any recommendation for a good simple library then would be best :)   Apps like javap are oriented to human readable output and therefore it has to be parsed and all the references resolved and that seems like wheel re-inventing.
Java or Ruby libraries would the best options for our build system.

Comment: I am not an expert in this area. You could turn to the software recommendation site on stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any external library, just use java.lang.Class. Write the name of your class:

```
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredFields(); 
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredConstructors();
[NameOfMyClass].class.getDeclaredMethods();
```

It's the same for interfaces and many other attributes.

Comment: Note this requires loading the class file into the app that wants to read those values.